# Yii2. Setting a custom controller namespace

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have  a controller in components/test/test/controllers folder, called MyController. If I set the namespace as "namespace app\components\test\test", and then I try to call the controller if says "Page Not Found".

I have been reading and I know that by default Yii2 sets namespace for controllers to "app\controllers".

Also know that you can change namespace for all controllers from config:

```
'controllerNamespace' => 'app\\components\test...'
```

But I just wanted to change for one controller not for all. Something similar to modules, there you can do:

```
$this->controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\test\test';
```

I just found there is something called "controllerMap", maybe this could be a solution? any ideas?

**Example**
I have created inside "components" (basic template) a controller LocationController with this content:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\web\Controller;

class LocationController extends Controller  {

    public function actionAdd() {

        return "hola1";
    }

    public function actionRemove() {
        return "hola2";
    }

}
```

When I created a link Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl("location/add"); and click on it I get "Page not found" error.

**UPDATE**
I have found that is possible to add classes to classMap, but not sure where to place it:

```
Yii::$classMap['app\components\LocationController'] = '..path.../components/LocaitonController.php'
```

Maybe this could do the trick?

Comment: You have a typo namespace app\components\test/test

Comment: Thanks, I've just fix it (it was a type on the question only), any ideas how can it be done?

Comment: are you sure you are calling the right  controllerAction? .. please provide  the url ..

Comment: @scaisEdge. Thanks. I am using standard Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl("test/test"). When is used in a different namespace, should this be changed?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: No .. i have never user classMap .. but the problem  is that you are using components or modules in a different way respect the standard yii2 way .. i suggest you a deep  study of the yii2 guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html , http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-components.html, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html .. this concept are strictly defined in yii2

Comment: I guessed that was a difficult one. I will keep digging. thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: Once you have understand  how yii2 work  .. is not difficult .. but if you try to code freely .. is not easy keep the result inside yii2

Comment: Thanks. the idea is always pushing the limits to learn something new, if at the end there is no way to do it as I was planning, I will find another way between framework limits. Is there a way to emulate actions in example for a widget? I found a discussion about it on yii2 github and they mentioned something related to behaviors, maybe I can do it with that.

Comment: That's the right way ..

Answer (score 0):

About your "Not found" problem, your controllerNamespace and namespace must have the full path of the controller, in your case:

```
app\modules\test\test\controllers
```

Now,to change the path for a single controller I can only think of creating a Module inside your app (like you mentioned):

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\test\test;

/**
 * module definition class
 */
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\test\test\controllers';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

And add in your config the module:

```
$config = [
    ...
    'modules' => [
        'module' => 'app\modules\test\test\Module'
    ]
];
```

**EDIT**

You can also add in your config:

```
$config = [
    ...
   'controllerMap' => [
       'location' => 'app\components\LocationController',
   ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My controller is not in a module. That was an example about how is done in modules, please see my updated question with an example.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you are confusing [Components](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html) with [Modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html). The definition of Modules states that: `Modules are self-contained software units that consist of models, views, controllers, and other supporting components.`. While Components `provide different services for processing requests`.

Comment: Actually that was just for example purposes, I am actually trying to do it for a widget that I have inside components ;). Just wondering if that is possible or not